# Added my first package with API Integration Component. How to test an API call (SOAP or REST)?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest, soap, package-install

I am a developer but I admit I am confused by going through the [Marketing Cloud API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm).

Inside our Marketing Cloud's installed packages, I created a new package and added an **API Integration** component to it. I then chose the integration type of *Server-to-Server*. I got the following endpoints and information about my integration:
[image]

The first thing I would like to test is to update a field on the All Subscribers list for a specific subscriber.

Could somebody guide me through how do I prepare the request and how to do a very basic test?

Comment: @zuzannamj Thank you! Looks very useful and I will definitely go through the Postman tutorial. Could you please point to how to make a call once the token process is complete and how to build a request to e.g. update the All Subscribers list?

Comment: Take a look at Eliot's gist here: https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/f29a78abba23020d8465

Comment: Yes, I've actually seen this one, too. Ok, maybe last question: Do we need a new token for each request? And is there a reference page in which we see the entire XML structure of the object?

Comment: No, the token is valid for 20 minutes and you can use it as many times as you like. For a full list of objects, see here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm

Comment: @zuzannamj ok thank you very much! Do you think we should delete/close this question, then?